# Struct within struct, using typedef and arrays

Tags: c, arrays, struct, typedef

**UPDATE: Code is correct and sensible, comments provide how to assign values to struct variables**

I am writing a struct in C that contains 2 integer arrays and an array of custom-defined type 'info'. This 'info' type just contains several int variables. Here is the piece of code that I've come up with having done a bit of searching around the web:

```
typedef struct info {
    int test_count;
    int skip_count;
    int prime_count;
} info;

struct myStruct {
    int arr1[10];
    int arr2[20];
    info info[20];
};
```

This does not generate any compiler warnings or errors, but is it the most sensible implementation given what I'm trying to do?

Also– How would I assign values to the info variables and then access them through myStruct? I've tried various statements using the dot operator, but I cannot get them past the compiler.

Comment: Looks OK to me. Example usage `struct myStruct x;  x.info[3].skip_count = 4;`

Comment: Please show the source in question, and the errors.

Comment: It is valid C as the compiler said by not complaining.  Whether it is suitable depends on what you want to do with it.  For example, why is the 10 not 20?  If it were 20 too, would you be better of with an alternative structure containing a pair of `int` values and an `info`.  May I observe that using `info` for quite so many purposes (structure tag, typedef name, structure element name) is rather thorough — aka potentially confusing; there's only labels in the non-preprocessor name spaces left to use.

Comment: And given: `struct myStruct x;` you should be able to use `x.info[13].prime_count` to access an element of that array.

Comment: did you try the method @JonathanLeffler suggested? If yes, what error did you get? update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK to me. Example usage `struct myStruct x;  x.info[3].skip_count = 4;`
                    – M.M

And given: `struct myStruct x;` you should be able to use `x.info[13].prime_count` to access an element of that array.
                    – Jonathan Leffler